# Firestore data modeling

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am creating a new Firestore database and am new to NoSQL. I am creating an application where I would need 4 root collections. Users, teams, challenges, and tournaments. Users need to join teams. Admins need to create challenges and tournaments. Tournaments need challenges and participants. I was wondering how this could be modeled the best in Firestore. This is what it looks like in JSON format so far:

```
{
  "users": {
    "uid": "user_id",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
  },
  "teams": {
    "members": {
      "user_id": {
        "uid": "user_id",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
      }
    },
    "teamName": "Team X",
    "teamPhoto": "url"
  },
  "challenges": {
    "doc1": {
      "challengeName": "name",
      "challengeDescription": "description"
    }
  },
  "tournaments": {
    "selectedChallenges": [
      {
        "challenge_doc1": {
          "challengeName": "name",
          "challengeDescription": "description"
        }
      }
    ],
    "tournamentName": "name"
  }
}
```

Comment: The current structure looks fine but can you also share what kind of queries you would need. Then it'll be easier to check if this structure works or can be modified. Also a tournament is essentially a group of challenges right?

Comment: I would need queries like get all the tournaments then display information about the challenges this tournament contains and let users join these challenges. Yes, that is what a tournament essentially is.

Comment: Do you only need a single query? We are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are the other queries?

Comment: Teams have users and tournaments have challenges but where's the link from tournaments to participants (or vice-versa). Also, while you can approach NoSQL this way, it typically doesn't work out the way you think it will. You should clearly define what queries you will need ( per @AlexMamo comment above). For example, *I want to know all tournaments that user Larry is part of*. Or, *How many teams are in a certain challenge*

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think I understand a bit better now. I'll try to figure it out myself and if I can't figure it out I'll ask with the queries I need to perform.